# Accessing remote Excel data sheets through JDBC connects successfully in case of wrong credential

Tags: java, jdbc, hxtt

I am connecting to remote excel file using jdbc driver:

```
Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:excel:smb://username:pass@host/path/Data.xlsx");
        System.out.println("Connected to " + "url" + " successfully");
```

It works fine, but when I enter wrong username/password it connects successfully too. How should I implement it to get exception when connecting with wrong credentials?

Comment: Which driver are you using, does it even need a username and password?

Comment: I am using com.hxtt.sql.excel.ExcelDriver driver and Excel_JDBC30.jar. For smb connection I am using jcifs-1.3.17.jar